# Save device token with FCM in ionic 2

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM plugin to do push notification for ionic2.
reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm

I followed https://github.com/edismooth/ionic2-firebase/tree/master

It works fine and I can received the push from firebase console. Now I want to build my own server to let admin to send push notification with own backend.

I faced one problem is : I can get the device token, however, I have no idea how to save it to local storage. The code is as below. May I know which part I am wrong? Is that “this.local.set” can’t be used within the function of “FCMPlugin.getToken”. If yes, how can I save the token and use out of this function? Many thanks.

```
initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
            FCMPlugin.getToken(
                function (token) {
                    console.log(token); //I can get the token data
                    this.local.set('tokenvalue', token); // the token value can't be saved to local storage like this
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
                }
            );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 - How to store global variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103557/ionic-2-how-to-store-global-variable)

Comment: what if i have login page ? I mean we get the token in `appp.js` but required same token after user login then ? any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First, try this `this.localStorage.set(...)`, if that doesn't work and you have access to the `window` object. Use `window.localStorage.setItem(...)`

Comment: I have debug on real device, it showed "TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of null", I guess inside the plugin function, we can't use ionic storage?

Comment: yes that's possible, did using `window.localStorage` directly not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic Storage.

I describe it in this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105221/902630