# Ionic 2 - How to store global variable?

Tags: ionic2

**THE SITUATION:**

In my app.component there is the login function. It is working properly and I get the user data from the API.

I need to store this data as a global variable to be able to access it throughout the app.

I thought that sharing a service was the way to do it, but unfortunately is not working as I thought.

**THE CODE**:

**The service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  public accountInfo;

  setUserData(value) 
  {
    this.accountInfo = value;
  }

  getUserData() {
    return this.accountInfo;
  }

}
```

**The app.component:**

```
loginSubmit()
{
    // Function reduced to what is essential to the question

    this.userService.submitLogin(email, password)
        .subscribe((response) => {

            if(response.result == 1) 
            {
                this.loginService.setUserData(response.account_info);

                var justTesting = this.loginService.getUserData();

                // Getting the proper result back
                console.log(justTesting);
            }

        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Trying to access the user data from another component:

```
this.accountInfo = this.loginService.getUserData();
console.log(this.accountInfo);
```

The result is `undefined`. Probably because this.accountInfo (in the service) is instantiated again when the service is called from the other component...

**THE QUESTION**:

How can I store some data as a global variable? Can it be done by sharing a service?

Thanks!

Comment: in the page where you are trying to get `this.accountInfo = this.loginService.getUserData();` check what is inside the `setUserData(value) ` if it is empty then only it is returning undefined you must checkthe set userdata

Comment: But setUserData is a function I called in order to set the global variable.

Comment: yes i understood that!. just try to  do `this.loginService.setUserData('wellcome');` in one of your page and then try to get the value in another page like `this.loginService.getUserData();` i am sure it will be printed.

Comment: Yes tested and working.

Comment: so that means you can call ` this.loginService.getUserData();` any of your component it will work untill you set the value of the setuserdata to null

Comment: may be some logic issue in your code check `this.setUserData(value)` you have used some where else

Comment: no setUserData() I don't use anywhere else. But I am afraid that by injecting the service in the other component - that value accountInfo get instantiated again and thus is undefined

Comment: You **can** share information by using a shared service. First make sure the service is a singleton (add the reference only in the `providers` array of the `ngModule`. If after that it does not work, maybe there's a syncronization issue. Add a console.log in both, the method that sets the value and the method that gets that value, to be sure that you're not trying to read it before it is set.

Comment: Yes thanks! It was indeed that problem! I just noticed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Matt answer is properly working and it offer a good solution to the problem.

I also found what was the problem in my code: The service had to be a singleton. I was instead injecting the service in the providers of the component.

And that was the problem because the service was instantiated again and thus `public accountInfo` lost his previous content.

You can share a service to store a global variable - but has to be a singleton - you need to inject it only once in the app.module.ts:

```
providers: [ LoginService ]
```

Comment: This is the Angular (and Ionic) way to do it, so it should be the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ionic provides a method for storing global variables with the `Storage` plugin. (`cordova-sqlite-storage`). Storage will attempt to use `IndexedDB`, `WebSQL`, and `localstorage`, in that order.

First add it to the providers list.

In `src/app.module.ts`

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    Storage
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And then inject it in your component

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(storage: Storage) {

     // set a key/value
     storage.set('name', 'Max');

     // Or to get a key/value pair
     storage.get('name').then((val) => {
       console.log('Your name is', val);
     })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found what was wrong in my code. The service was not a singleton. But I tested your solution too and is working very good! Just one question: storage is basically what was the localStorage for ionic 1? So in this way the data will be kept also when the app will be closed right?

Comment: When running in a native app context, Storage will prioritize using SQLite, as it's one of the most stable and widely used file-based databases, and avoids some of the pitfalls of things like localstorage and IndexedDB, such as the OS deciding to clear out such data in low disk-space situations.